The docs generated by fastapi are missing the correct interface
I built an application with Fastapi+MongoDB, the following code about it, when I tested it, I found that Fastapi's docs don't parse the send-code and verify-code interfaces, I searched for a lot of ways to do it but couldn't solve it, what's going on?
main.py:
@app.post("/send-code/")
async def send_code(phone_verification: PhoneVerification):
    if db.users.find_one({"phone_number": phone_verification.phone_number, "is_blacklisted": True}):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Phone number is blacklisted.")
    existing = db.phone_verifications.find_one({"phone_number": phone_verification.phone_number})
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    if existing:
        if existing['attempts'] >= 2:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Maximum request limit reached for today.")
        if (now - existing['last_attempt']).total_seconds() < 18000:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Request too soon. Wait for at least 5 hours.")
    phone_verification.attempts = (existing['attempts'] + 1) if existing else 1
    phone_verification.last_attempt = now
    phone_verification.created_at = now if not existing else existing['created_at']

    db.phone_verifications.update_one(
        {"phone_number": phone_verification.phone_number},
        {"$set": {
            "attempts": phone_verification.attempts,
            "last_attempt": phone_verification.last_attempt,
            "code": phone_verification.code,
            "created_at": phone_verification.created_at
        }},
        upsert=True
    )
    return {"message": "Verification code sent."}


@app.post("/verify-code/")
async def verify_code(phone_number: str, code: str):
    verification = db.phone_verifications.find_one({"phone_number": phone_number})
    if not verification or (datetime.utcnow() - verification['created_at']).total_seconds() > 3600:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Code is invalid or expired.")
    if verification['code'] == code:
        db.users.update_one({"phone_number": phone_number}, {"$set": {"phone_verified": True}})
        return {"message": "Phone number verified successfully."}
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid verification code.")

models.py:
class PhoneVerification(BaseModel):
    phone_number: str
    code: str = Field(default_factory=lambda: ''.join([str(randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(6)]))
    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow)
    attempts: int = 0
    last_attempt: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow)

    @validator('phone_number')
    def validate_phone_number(cls, v):
        pattern = re.compile(r'^1(3[0-9]|4[01456879]|5[0-35-9]|6[2567]|7[0-8]|8[0-9]|9[0-35-9])\d{8}$')
        if not pattern.match(v):
            raise ValueError("Invalid phone number format")
        return v

I tried to send it a request by sending it a request and it returned No Found.Here is the code for its minimal instantiation file:
import logging
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator
from datetime import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient
from random import randint
import re

app = FastAPI()
client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client.your_database

# 配置日志记录
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class PhoneVerification(BaseModel):
    phone_number: str
    code: str = Field(default_factory=lambda: ''.join([str(randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(6)]))
    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow)
    attempts: int = 0
    last_attempt: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow)

    @validator('phone_number')
    def validate_phone_number(cls, v):
        pattern = re.compile(r'^1(3[0-9]|4[01456879]|5[0-35-9]|6[2567]|7[0-8]|8[0-9]|9[0-35-9])\d{8}$')
        if not pattern.match(v):
            raise ValueError("Invalid phone number format")
        return v


@app.post("/send-code/")
async def send_code(phone_verification: PhoneVerification):
    logger.info(f"Received request to send code to {phone_verification.phone_number}")
    if db.users.find_one({"phone_number": phone_verification.phone_number, "is_blacklisted": True}):
        logger.warning(f"Phone number {phone_verification.phone_number} is blacklisted")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Phone number is blacklisted.")

    existing = db.phone_verifications.find_one({"phone_number": phone_verification.phone_number})
    now = datetime.utcnow()

    if existing:
        if existing['attempts'] >= 2:
            logger.warning(f"Maximum request limit reached for {phone_verification.phone_number}")
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Maximum request limit reached for today.")
        if (now - existing['last_attempt']).total_seconds() < 18000:
            logger.warning(f"Request too soon for {phone_verification.phone_number}")
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Request too soon. Wait for at least 5 hours.")

    phone_verification.attempts = (existing['attempts'] + 1) if existing else 1
    phone_verification.last_attempt = now
    phone_verification.created_at = now if not existing else existing['created_at']

    db.phone_verifications.update_one(
        {"phone_number": phone_verification.phone_number},
        {"$set": {
            "attempts": phone_verification.attempts,
            "last_attempt": phone_verification.last_attempt,
            "code": phone_verification.code,
            "created_at": phone_verification.created_at
        }},
        upsert=True
    )

    logger.info(f"Verification code sent to {phone_verification.phone_number}")
    return {"message": "Verification code sent."}


@app.post("/verify-code/")
async def verify_code(phone_number: str, code: str):
    logger.info(f"Received request to verify code for {phone_number}")
    verification = db.phone_verifications.find_one({"phone_number": phone_number})

    if not verification or (datetime.utcnow() - verification['created_at']).total_seconds() > 3600:
        logger.warning(f"Code is invalid or expired for {phone_number}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Code is invalid or expired.")

    if verification['code'] == code:
        db.users.update_one({"phone_number": phone_number}, {"$set": {"phone_verified": True}})
        logger.info(f"Phone number {phone_number} verified successfully")
        return {"message": "Phone number verified successfully."}
    else:
        logger.warning(f"Invalid verification code for {phone_number}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid verification code.")



What request did you send that gave you a 404 / Not found? How are you running your application? What does the startup log show? What endpoints does the docs interface show?
